# How to perform an CRUD operations of employee details in a text file from stored procedure using oracle db by java programming

Tags: java, text-files, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to perform an CRUD operations of employee details
in a text file from stored procedure using oracle db by 
java programming.

Please provide an solution.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertEMP(
    p_Eno IN EMP2.Eno%TYPE,
    p_Ename IN EMP2.Ename%TYPE,
    p_Designation IN EMP2.Designation%TYPE,
    p_Salary IN EMP2.Salary%TYPE,
         p_Ename IN EMP2.DOB%TYPE,)
IS
BEGIN
 
  INSERT INTO EMP2 ("Eno", "Ename", "Designation", "Salary","DOB"); 
  VALUES (p_Eno, p_Ename,p_Designation, p_Salary,p_DOB);
 
  COMMIT;
 
END;
/

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: how to retrieve stored procedure contents to .txt file in oracle sql

Comment: Your procedure is not returning anything. Anyway if in such case, you'll have to call the procedure in java, and write the results into .txt file.